# (XCode Autolayout) Label/Button position&size keep changing over time

Tags: ios, xcode

Hi I'm new to Xcode and I have been checking out ObjC tutorials lately and I started playing around with the storyboard.

So What I did was:

1. Drag some buttons/labels onto a view in storyboard
2. Set the size & position using the size inspector
3. Build and preview the app on the iPad

It looked fine at the beginning, but then I noticed that the position and size of the buttons/labels kept changing over time (by like a few pixels) as I built the project for a number of times.

I have not change (or set) anything about insets/constraints yet.
Can anyone please advise as I dont think anyone would be happy for changing the position & size when there is over 100+ UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you have created the layout for one pixel density and implement on different pixel density. Which means you to exactly see what you are making build the layout in also ipad (you can change it in the storyboard see below).

Comment: Sorry I don't quite get what you are getting at. :(

Comment: But what I mean is that the values of position/size in the size inspector kept changing (sorry about my english)

Comment: @Alain in which device are you using to build the in the storyboard. Check below in viewController. You will see something like **viewas : Iphone 6s** or something.

Comment: "iPad Pro 9.7". (I know it is not the same in terms of screen size but this seems to be the closet as I build the app into a Retina iPad)

Comment: How much is the position chainging ? Have you tried to change the storyboard when in another view other than ipad ?

Comment: Let's say I have a button on a view (namely "view 1", and I have set these values in size inspector --- x: 100, y: 120, width: 200, height: 50). The above values would change over time (all values are off by 1-2) after I do some modifying on other views in the same storyboard. (But at the mean time I have not changed anything in "view 1"). If I leave it like that, I would see the difference getting slightly larger.

Comment: Don't know man .. May be some bug of xcode. Try using constraints. Good luck.